# i have created two custom view and i want to switch that view

Tags: android

Why this code is not working? it always force to end  I want to switch the view but it is not happening. Either it forces to kill or show black screen. I am want to switch the four views. ar how to create the animation?

```
 public class DrawDemoActivity extends Activity {
        DemoView demoview ;
        FinalView finalview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean first=true;
        boolean sec=false;
        demoview = new DemoView(this);
        finalview = new FinalView(this);
           // for contnivew switching the view 
        for(int i=0;i>0;i++)
        {
            if (first==true||sec==false)
            {
                setContentView(finalview);
                first=false;
                sec=true;
            }else if(first==false||sec==true)
            {
                setContentView(demoview);
                first=true;
                sec=true;
            }else if(first==true||sec==true)
            {
                setContentView(demoview);
                first=false;
                sec=false;
            }else
            {   
                setContentView(demoview);
                first=false;
                sec=false;
            }
        }
    }
//first view 
    private class DemoView extends View{
        public DemoView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // custom drawing code here
            // remember: y increases from top to bottom
            // x increases from left to right
            int x = 150;
            int y = 200;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            // make the entire canvas white
            paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // another way to do this is to use:
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            // draw blue circle with antialiasing turned on
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(x-24, y+30, 11, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);            
            canvas.drawLine(0, 300 , 320, 300, paint);
        }
    }
    //second view 
        private class FinalView extends View {
            public FinalView(Context context){
        super(context);
        }

            @Override 
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                // custom drawing code here
                // remember: y increases from top to bottom
                // x increases from left to right
                int x = 150;
                int y = 200;
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                // make the entire canvas white
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                // another way to do this is to use:
                // canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                // draw blue circle with antialiasing turned on
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);


                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x-11, y+19, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y+38, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x+20, y+30, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x-11, y-19, 11, paint);


                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle(x+41, y+30, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x+20, y+9, 11, paint);
                canvas.drawCircle(x-23, y-37, 11, paint);

                canvas.drawLine(0, 300 , 320, 300, paint);      
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: use viewFlipper to switch view in an Activity, use are doing in wrong manner, see [here](http://oudomvilla.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/)

Comment: anand thaks but i want to show the animation then hw should i do this.i want to show something then disappera then again show that in the view .

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your `setContentView()` will not get called since the you for loop never iterate

```
for(int i=0;i>0;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `onCreate` method. the `setContentView` method is unreachable due to the for loop, where `i` is never greater than zero. `int i=0;i>0;i++`

Also, as Anand mentioned above use `ViewFlipper` in case you want to switch views. You can find a  good example [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

Comment: @Ashishsingh -- can you tell me whats happening?In case of error logcat entries would help.

Comment: it is just throwing exception error around 32 type of error .

Answer (score 0):

use view flipper and you can set animation for their in and out, just before of calling next viewFlipper. below is something may be usefull..

```
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(pushUpIn);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(pushUpOut);
viewFlipper.showNext();
```